# How to send report directly to the printer?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I am using Apex 18.2. and ORDS as a printing server.
I have a master-detail page for selling items with a form on a table as the master region and an IG as the detail, joined to each other through assigning the PK to the FK IG's column. 
There is another page with a report that can be queried through number of page items to get the documents with items sold in the previously mentioned master-detail page.
Whenever a user creates a document and submit the page, I will need to send the data of that document directly to the printer. 
I mentioned the report page because I thought redirecting to it and assigning the PK to the corresponding page item could be a suggestion. But I know that I can create a shared component> report query too. But I do not know how could I send the data directly to the printer in either way. 
I do not know if the report type - IR, CR or IG would make a difference. That's why I just referred to "report". But I'd need to know how it could be done with all types of reports.
Here is how a real-world scenario would look like,
You enter a supermarket, buy some items, go to the cashier, pay for what you've bought and get a receipt. The receipt is printed when the cashier saves the invoice.

I know this is not how web apps work, but this is the task I am facing.
I can think of branching to the report page after the invoice is saved and setting the PK value to the corresponding page item in the "search criteria" region to get the corresponding data then execute "window.print()". But there will be two problems then. 1- criteria region would be printed too, unless I hide it with a dynamic action or else. 2- The "print dialog box" of the browser will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

APEX 20.1 added native support for PDF printing of Interactive Grid regions. See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1yIFcEdW_o

If you can't upgrade, or if that support isn't sufficient for your needs, I suggest taking a look at APEX Office Print: https://www.apexofficeprint.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks Dan. Unfortunately, the regions or report queries printing features available are either to download it or open it in the browser aka inline. I am talking about sending the data directly to the physical printer without getting obstructed by the browser's print preview dialog box or the printer's. 
Chrome has a keyword that can be added to the shortcut that initiates the app which is --disable-print-preview. I was searching for a programmatic solution.

Comment: Have you read this? http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2020/01/print-pdf-from-oracle-apex-to-local.html

Comment: I came across it but I know AOP is not free and the offer of a free number of reports is a cloud offer not an offline one which I need. And if I am not paying for the main development framework - Apex then of course I am not paying for a report engine. I hope I could be able to someday. Wish me luck.

Comment: You'll pay for it one way or another. :) Either with your time (to build and maintain something similar) or with money. Frankly, the same is true with APEX itself. Sure, you have the XE database and the Oracle Cloud free tier. Given your needs, it sounds like your on XE, which is a great free database. But you still have to play DBA (backup, recovery, etc.). Again, that's your time that could be invested in your product. I hear you though, it can be tough making the trasition (chicken or egg problem). Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

APEX Office Print(AOP) can provide you the right solution.

Please try out the solution posted in the below link.

http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2020/01/print-pdf-from-oracle-apex-to-local.html

Few more examples:

1. How to print to an IP printer:

   https://www.apexofficeprint.com/ords/aop_web/r/aop_sample_app_web/5034?session=13740999314649
2. How to print directly to a zebra printer

   https://www.apexofficeprint.com/ords/aop_web/r/aop_sample_app_web/zebra-printer?session=6208952429228

   (OR)

   https://dgielis.blogspot.com/2020/01/printing-to-local-zebra-printer-from.html

If you are redirected to the Home page,
-> Click on examples in the left side menu.
-> Click on Print(highlighted in yellow).

[image]

Comment: I am searching for a free solution. You would help me if you tell me how they implemented it.